# Child height in SplitLayoutPanel

Tags: gwt, layout, gwt2

I've got a SplitLayoutPanel. In the North cell, I've got a ScrollPanel 
with a tree on it. 
I want this ScrollPanel height to be the same of the north cell, so 
when the tree expand, a scroll appears. The size of this ScrollPanel 
must changed when the north cell is resized. 
I've tried with RequireResizes but parent does not send size 
information... An ideal approach should be that ProvidesSize widgets call onResize method with available size for the RequiresSize widget children

I'm very confused. How to configure SplitLayoutPanel to have cell 
children resized ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class that extends Composite and implement RequiresResize; like so:

```
public class MyScrollPanel extends Composite implements RequiresResize {
 private ScrollPanel scrollPanel;

 public MyScrollPanel() {
  scrollPanel = new ScrollPanel();
  initWidget(scrollPanel);
 }

 public void onResize() {
  // do something to your scrollpanel
 }

}
```

Then add MyScrollPanel to the north cell in your SplitLayoutPanel.

**EDIT**

 However. It turns out ScrollPanel already has the desired behavior by default. A ScrollPanel added to a SplitLayoutPanel cell will automatically fill the size of the cell, even on resize. And any ScrollPanel child widget larger than available space will cause a scrollbar to appear.


But make sure you're adding the SplitLayoutPanel to the RootLayoutPanel by doing 
`RootLayoutPanel.get().add(splitLayoutPanel);`

Comment: `Composite` +  `RequiresResize` = `ResizeComposite`. And all panels between the `MyScrollPanel` and the `SplitLayouPanel` must be Layout panels, otherwise the resize is not called in the `MyScrollPanel` panel.

Comment: According to the docs, ResizeComposite automatically delegates the onResize to the wrapped widget which must itself implement RequiresResize, so that won't work with a ScrollPanel.  As for the other note, all widgets sitting between SplitLayoutPanel and MyScrollPanel must not be Layout panels, but have to implement ProvidesResize, or MyScrollPanel.onResize() won't be called.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that is exactly what I've done but I don't know what to put on the onResize method. How to set the height of my ScrollPanel equals to the height of the north cell ? This is really tricky to check the parent in a child widget because you can't reuse your child widget in another parent...

Comment: I just added a ScrollPanel to the north cell of a SplitLayoutPanel, and it fills the north cell completely. And continues to do so when I resize the cell. Any content that's bigger than the space available will cause a scrollbar to appear. So the functionality you're looking for is already there by default. Make sure you're using RootLayoutPanel.get().add(new TheSplitLayoutPanel()) and that the ScrollPanel is the only child in the north cell.

Comment: ooops, you're right... It's because I have an intermediate panel... Thank you... I'm really tired !

Comment: Go to bed! No wait, there's no time for that. Take a 4 min nap. :)